# How to pass parameters in a request?

Tags: java, android, jquery, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to put data from the NewOrderRequest(pojo) class into the parameters :

```
 @Query("params") NewOrderRequest params
```

**but I get this result:**

*resultQueryString: params com.example.city.Model.NewOrderRequest@f45c8ad*

**expectation result:**

*resultQueryString: params +911*

**Data setting:**

```
NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest = new NewOrderRequest();
        newOrderRequest.setPhone("+911");
        NetworkService.getInstance()
                .service()
                .newOrder(newOrderRequest)
```

**Request:**

```
@Headers({"Accept:application/json", "Content-Type:application/json;"})
@POST("RemoteCall?method=Taxi.WebAPI.NewOrder")
Call<RegResponse>newOrder(@Header("Cookie") String setCookie,@Query("params") NewOrderRequest params);
```

**Please tell me how to pass the phone to the parameter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an **Object** in `@Query` param, Only `@Body` accepts the object as its param. What you want is to convert your Object into JsonObject. I assume you're using Gson Library.

```
NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest = new NewOrderRequest();
        newOrderRequest.setPhone("+911");
        NetworkService.getInstance()
                .service()
                .newOrder(new Gson().toJson(newOrderRequest))
```

Comment: @Geferson I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
@Headers({"Accept:application/json", "Content-Type:application/json;"})
@POST("RemoteCall?method=Taxi.WebAPI.NewOrder")
Call<RegResponse>newOrder(@Header("Cookie") String setCookie,@Query("params") String phone);
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: NewOrderRequest cannot be converted to String

Answer (score 0):

As it is a post request, and the intention is to send the data as an json object, the data is better sent in the request body rather than query param. Also any sensitive details should be part of request body.

Comment: The api to which I refer will accept only a json object as a parameter.